# hadoop error not able to place enough replicas

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I am using hadoop 1.2.1. It was active for about 2 years. Now following error start to appear in logs and hbase 0.94.14 could not connect with it.

NameNode Error:

```
2016-03-09 11:57:23,965 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Not able to place enough replicas, still in need of 1 to reach 2
Not able to place enough replicas
2016-03-09 11:57:23,965 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Not able to place enough replicas, still in need of 1 to reach 2
Not able to place enough replicas
2016-03-09 11:57:23,965 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Not able to place enough replicas, still in need of 1 to reach 2
Not able to place enough replicas
2016-03-09 11:57:26,966 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Not able to place enough replicas, still in need of 1 to reach 2
Not able to place enough replicas
```

And in hbase master log file error is like following

```
2016-03-09 11:16:31,192 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.AssignmentManager$TimeoutMonitor: node1,12000,1457504177336.timeoutMonitor exiting
2016-03-09 11:16:31,193 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.SplitLogManager$TimeoutMonitor: node1,12000,1457504177336.splitLogManagerTimeoutMonitor exiting
2016-03-09 11:16:31,192 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.AssignmentManager$TimerUpdater: node1,12000,1457504177336.timerUpdater exiting
2016-03-09 11:16:31,218 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Session: 0x2535a0114bb0001 closed
2016-03-09 11:16:31,218 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: EventThread shut down
2016-03-09 11:16:31,218 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster: HMaster main thread exiting
2016-03-09 11:16:31,218 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine: Failed to start master
java.lang.RuntimeException: HMaster Aborted
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.startMaster(HMasterCommandLine.java:160)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.run(HMasterCommandLine.java:104)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ServerCommandLine.doMain(ServerCommandLine.java:76)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.main(HMaster.java:2120)
Wed Mar  9 11:22:26 PKT 2016 Stopping hbase (via master)
```

where is the problem. I have found a post who suggest that you should delete all data and format namdenode but I cannot do that as I cannot backup data.

This is the cluster summery

```
Configured Capacity: 3293363527680 (3 TB)
Present Capacity: 2630143946752 (2.39 TB)
DFS Remaining: 1867333337088 (1.7 TB)
DFS Used: 762810609664 (710.42 GB)
DFS Used%: 29%
Under replicated blocks: 35
Blocks with corrupt replicas: 0
Missing blocks: 0

-------------------------------------------------
Datanodes available: 3 (3 total, 0 dead)

Name: 10.11.21.44:50010
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 441499058176 (411.18 GB)
DFS Used: 246261780480 (229.35 GB)
Non DFS Used: 194947321856 (181.56 GB)
DFS Remaining: 289955840(276.52 MB)
DFS Used%: 55.78%
DFS Remaining%: 0.07%
Last contact: Thu Mar 10 15:20:15 PKT 2016


Name: 10.11.21.42:50010
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 2410365411328 (2.19 TB)
DFS Used: 304959569920 (284.02 GB)
Non DFS Used: 238646935552 (222.26 GB)
DFS Remaining: 1866758905856(1.7 TB)
DFS Used%: 12.65%
DFS Remaining%: 77.45%
Last contact: Thu Mar 10 15:20:15 PKT 2016


Name: 10.11.21.43:50010
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 441499058176 (411.18 GB)
DFS Used: 211589259264 (197.06 GB)
Non DFS Used: 229625323520 (213.86 GB)
DFS Remaining: 284475392(271.3 MB)
DFS Used%: 47.93%
DFS Remaining%: 0.06%
Last contact: Thu Mar 10 15:20:16 PKT 2016
```

Comment: Could you paste the cluster summary here? ```dfs dfsadmin -report```

Comment: I have updated question

Comment: You have to run the balancer and also delete files because your cluster is full.

Comment: What files should I delete?

Comment: I run balancer. It gives following error                                                 WARN balancer.Balancer: Error moving block 385960552852994184 from 10.11.21.42:50010 to 10.11.21.43:50010 through 10.11.21.42:50010: block move is failed

Comment: You have to delete data. Your cluster is too full.

Comment: I have an extra disk where I should place to avoid deletion i.e. datanode or namenode machine

Comment: Wherever you have an open SATA port.

Comment: I have sata port on datanode1

Comment: I have added a new disk in a datanode but same error is going to apprear. I have updated dfsadmin -report output in question ?

Comment: You have to add the drive to the system, but you need to delete data anyways and use proper resource planning to avoid situations like this